# Как исправить ошибку 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server?

Tags: yii2, heroku

Для деплоя yii2 использую heroku но вот возникла ошибка `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server` нашел что эта ошибка решается путем `Procfile.txt` только я не понял куда надо класть этот фаил, и какие настройки указывать в нем.
вот

```
heroku logs

[Fri Feb 02 06:57:35.114423 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 119:tid 140078179964672] [client 10.141.244.173:24243] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
2018-02-02T06:57:35.116929+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.141.244.173 - - [02/Feb/2018:06:57:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
root@sergalas-Lenovo-Z710:/var/www/yii2phone.loc#
```